# ipython and many things work only when i use sudo

Tags: python, redhat

I am having strange issue of python3.6 on redhat 7.4

Launching ipython3 works when i use sudo.

```
sudo ipython3
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct 11 2017, 18:17:37)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from flask import Flask

In [3]: exit
```

But as a normal user i hit the error below

```
$ ipython3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython3", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
**ImportError: cannot import name 'start_ipython'**
```

Any ideas whats wrong here

```
python3.6 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']

sudo python3.6 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
'/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']


which ipython3
/usr/local/bin/ipython3
sudo which ipython3
ls -ltr /bin/ipython3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Oct 31 14:11 /bin/ipython3 -> /usr/local/bin/ipython3
```

Comment: What is the output of `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` and `sudo python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`?

Comment: also `which ipython3` and `sudo which ipython3`. There might some difference in the `PATH` env variable between the root user and your user that could explain this.

Comment: Another possible reason is that the IPython library has been installed somewhere where only root has read permission. I don't know how that would happen, but it's not impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to run `strace ipython3` as a regular user (where things are not working) and look at the log to spot the `EACCES` errors.  Then you can fix the permissions for those files/directories.

Is the regular user unconfined?  If not, you need to watch out for SELinux problems as well.